# How many to many relationship table do I draw data with code-first?

Tags: c#, list, ef-code-first

I have two tables in my student's name and course name. There is a lot of relationship between them. How do I draw the lessons of the learner? Below are the entities I wrote.

```
public class Student
{
        public Student()
        {
            Lessons = new HashSet<Lesson>();
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int MaxCredit { get; set; }
        public int MemberID { get; set; }
        public virtual Member Member { get; 
        public virtual ICollection<Lesson> Lessons { get; set; }
}

public class Lesson
{
        public Lesson()
        {
            Students = new HashSet<Student>();
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int LessonCredit { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to get a students lessons with:

```
uow.LessonRepository.GetALL().Where(x=> x.Students.Any(s=> s.MemberID==id))
```

but it gave me a casting error.

Comment: You seem to have it; what isn't working with that code?

Comment: For example, if I want to take the lessons of student x, how do I take it?

Comment: Just access the `Lessons` property of the `Student` object. Does that not work?

Comment: I am using EntityFramework. I'm trying something like this. But it says cast. I could not figure out why he wanted to cast something that was already on the list.

_uow.LessonRepository.GetALL().Where(x=> x.Students.Any(s=> s.MemberID==id));

Comment: Please be more specific with your error then (and the code using it) Your EF model looks correct. That code is a *start* though it seems a bit non-sensical. If you want a students lessons why not do something like `students.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == id).Lessons`? In your code you need to show what you are assigning that to, again the specific casting error would be nice.

Comment: I did not understand how to do it. How would you do if you were?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, hopefully my full answer makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your EF model is correct, to do a many to many relationship both sides have a `virtual ICollection<T>` of the other type.

Your query isn't right though if you want to get a student's lessons, parsing it we start with a `LessonRepository` (presumably an `IEnumerable<Lesson>`) and then do a `Where` on it to filter the collection down; so far so good (a bit odd starting with the lessons, but whatever). The condition is (in English) where there are any students with a `MemberId` matching "id" (wherever that came from). Not exactly sure what that would give you, but its not a student's lessons.

Since you already have the navigation property, you can just access the `Lessons` property of a given student object. Assuming you started with a student id something like:

```
Students.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == id)?.Lessons;
```

`FirstOrDefault` searches for the correct student item and then you just access the `Lessons` property.